# Is there a way to edit/change the payload of a ICMP ping request?

Tags: ping, icmp

I was using Wireshark to take a peak at the contents of the ping payload. It is just a string of the lowercase alphabet in ASCII.

Is there a way to change this to send messages in a ping?